# How do I make a full deck of cards in a tkinter GUI?

Tags: tkinter

I have jpegs of all 52 cards that I'd like to use for a game of BlackJack. This is the code I have now to open an image, but if I were to do this for every card, it would take me over 200 lines.

```
ace = Image.open("filepath")
ace = ace.resize((50,75), Image.ANTIALIAS)
ace = ImageTk.PhotoImage(ace)
acelabel = Label(image = ace)
```

I've tried using a loop like the following, but then it doesn't actually affect the ace variable and instead raises an error.

```
ace = Image.open("File Path")
card_deck = [ace]
for i in card_deck:
    i = i.resize((50,75), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    i = ImageTk.PhotoImage(i)
acelabel = Label(image = ace)
```

Does anyone have any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing special you need to do, just do it like you would create strings or numbers or any other sort of object. It might look something like this:

```
cards = ["ace", "queen", "king", ...]

images = {}
labels = {}
for card_name in cards:
    filename = f"{card_name}.png"
    image = Image.open(filename)
    image = image.resize((50, 75), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    label = Label(image=image)
    images[card] = image
    labels[card] = label
```

Then, you can reference the images and labels like `images['ace']`, `labels['ace']`, etc.